# Rotating a node in SceneKit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, rotation, scenekit

I'm struggling to understand multiple rotations of a node.

Firstly, I created and positioned a plane:

```
SCNPlane *plane = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:10 height:10];
SCNNode *planeNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:plane];
planeNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, (M_PI/2 * 3));
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:planeNode];
```

Then I positioned and set the direction of a spotlight node on this plane:

```
SCNLight *light = [[SCNLight alloc] init];
light.type = SCNLightTypeSpot;
light.spotInnerAngle = 70;
light.spotOuterAngle = 100;
light.castsShadow = YES;
lightNode = [SCNNode node];
lightNode.light = light;
lightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(4, 0, 0.5);
lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI/2);
[planeNode addChildNode:lightNode];
```

Then I animate the rotation of the light node 90 degrees clockwise around the x-axis:

```
[SCNTransaction begin];
[SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0];

lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, M_PI/2);

[SCNTransaction commit];
```

But I'm confused as to why the following rotates the light node back to the original position about the same axis:

```
[SCNTransaction begin];
[SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0];

lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI/2);

[SCNTransaction commit];
```

To me this reads as we're rotating the node 90 degrees clockwise about the y-axis.

Can anyone explain why this works? Or, better yet, suggest a clearer method for rotating a node then returning it to its original position?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I've resolved this by using eulerAngles which seems to work in a way to what I understand.

So I replaced:

```
lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI/2);
```

With:

```
lightNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, M_PI/2, 0);
```

And likewise for the other rotations.

I have to admit I'm still very confused as to what the rotation method does but happy I have something I can work with now.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure to fully understand the question, but when you write `lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI/2);` you are not concatenating a rotation the node's current rotation. You are specifying a new "absolute" rotation.

As `SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI/2)` was the orignal rotation of `lightNode`, setting `SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI/2)` again will make the node rotate back to its original state.

**EDIT**

the following code does two things

1. first it sets an initial value for the node's rotation
2. then it specifies a new value for the node's rotation. Because it is done in a transaction (whose duration is not 0) SceneKit will animate that change. But the parameters of the animation, **including the rotation axis**, are chosen by SceneKit.

   ```
   lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, M_PI/2);

   [SCNTransaction begin];
   [SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0];
   lightNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, M_PI/2);
   [SCNTransaction commit];
   ```

It's the same for the `position` property.
The following code animates a node's position from `(1,0,1)` to `(2,3,4)`, not from `(1,1,1)` to `(3,3,5)`.

```
    aNode.position = SCNVector3Make(1, 0, 1);

    [SCNTransaction begin];
    [SCNTransaction setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    aNode.position = SCNVector3Make(2, 3, 4);
    [SCNTransaction commit];
```

it you want to animate a node, and want to be able to control the animation parameters, you can use a `CABasicAnimation` with a `byValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply although I think I'm now more confused than I was before :( I'm not at all sure what an absolute rotation is compared to what I'm trying to do here (simply rotate the light node in relation to the plane). I guess my question is basically: How can I rotate a node one way and then back to its original position working in relation to the same axis both times? If what I've done has resulted in an absolute rotation (which I'm guessing is bad), is there another method I should be using to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Thanks again for your response. Not sure this is what I'm after however since I don't want SceneKit choosing the axis of rotation for my animation; I need a very specific movement in a given direction. It looks to me like eulerAngles gives me this level of control plus it doesn't confuse me by switching the axis of rotation I need to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Because this shows up first when you search "scnnode rotate"

```
node.localRotate(by: SCNQuaternion(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.7071, w: 0.7071))
```